# コンタクトフォームで複数の項目を入力必須にしたい

Tags: php, html

名前とメールアドレスとお問い合わせの３項目を入力しないと送信できないようにしたいのですが、send.phpとゆうファイルの所にmail関数、isset関数を定義してissetの方に値があればtrue、なければfalthにしたいのですがうまく行きません。解決方法教えてもらえますでしょうか。

**index.php**

```
<form action="send.php" method="POST">
        <div class="form-content pt-5">
          <div class="form-left ">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="名前">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mt-5">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="メールアドレス">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-right">
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="お問い合わせ" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="上記の内容で送信する" class="text-center" id="button"></p>
      </form>
```

**send.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $emailFrom = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $mailTo = "example@example.com";
    $headers = "From: ".$emailFrom;
    $txt ="You have received an e-mail from " .$name.".\n\n".$message;

    if (mail($mailTo, $headers , $txt) && isset($mailTo, $headers , $txt)) {
        echo "<h1>お問い合わせありがとうございます"." ".$name."様。折り返し<br>連絡いたしますので、今しばらくお待ちください。</h1>";

    } else {
        echo "<h1 class='text-danger'>送信できませんでした。全項目ご入力ください。</h1>";

    }

}
```

Comment: 「うまくいきません」。とありますがどのような動作を期待して、どのような動作になってしまうのか具体的に記述をしてみてください。例えば「$mailTo宛にメールが届くはずなのですがメールが送信されるはずなのですが、届きません」とか「ありがとうメッセージが表示されるはずなのですが、常に送信できませんというメッセージが表示される」等ですね

Comment: ifの条件で、mail関数を実行しています。

Comment: メールは送れます。どのような動作を期待してるかとゆうとinputタグとtextareaタグの全項目入力したときのみメールを送信できるようにしたいです。今のコードですと、何も入力してなくてもメールが送信できるようになってしまってます。

Comment: 補足事項はコメントでなく本文編集でどうぞ。あと、提示コードには XSS 脆弱性があります、要対処。

Comment: see also; https://teratail.com/questions/264926

Answer (score 0):

ifの条件で、mail関数を実行しています。
入力の有無などの検証後に、mail送信を実行すると良いでしょう。

```
　
if(isset($mailTo, $headers , $txt)) {
    if ( mail( $mailTo, $headers, $txt ) ) {
        echo "お問い合わせありがとうございます" . " " . $name . "様。折り返し連絡いたしますので、今しばらくお待ちください。";
    } else {
        echo "送信できませんでした。全項目ご入力ください。";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

isset関数とmail関数との仕様を見直し、さらにHTMLのフォームの仕様を理解して、やりたい条件を確認しましょう。ちょっと長くて説明的ですが、これを理解しないとPHPの基礎の部分になりますので是非理解してください。

> 名前とメールアドレスとお問い合わせの３項目を入力しないと送信できないようにしたい

もうちょっとプログラム的な条件に落とし込むと

> 「$_POST['name']が空じゃない」かつ「$_POST['email']が空じゃない」かつ  「$_POST['message']が空じゃない」

かと思います。

しかしソースコード中のif分を見てみると

```
mail($mailTo, $headers , $txt) && isset($mailTo, $headers , $txt)
```

とあり

> 「mail関数の結果が真」かつ「$mailTo, $headers , $txtそれぞれがnullでない」

という条件になります
php: mail関数が偽になる条件としてはマニュアルによると
https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.mail.php

> メール送信が受け入れられた場合に TRUE 、それ以外の場合に FALSE を返します。
>   メールの配送が受け入れられたかどうかが基準であることに注意しましょう。 メールが実際にあて先に届いたかどうかでは「ありません」。

とあるので、この関数を呼び出した時点でメールの送信が試みてしまいます。

またissetも
https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.isset.php

> var が存在して NULL 以外の値をとれば TRUE、 そうでなければ FALSE を返します。

とありますが、
直前の部分で

```
$mailTo = "example@example.com";
$headers = "From: ".$emailFrom;
$txt ="You have received an e-mail from " .$name.".\n\n".$message;
```

それぞれの変数にnull以外の値を代入しているのでissetがfalseになることはないです。

さらにHTMLのフォームの仕様としてPOSTしてくるデータはnullになることはないです。
入力データがないと空文字で送信されます。空文字とnullは違いますのでご注意ください。
つまりPOSTデータのデータのチェックでissetは使えないということになります。

ではどのように記述するかというと

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$emailFrom = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if($name != "" && $emailFrom != "" && $message != "")) {
   //すべての入力値が空じゃない場合にメールの生成処理
   $mailTo = "example@example.com";
   $headers = "From: ".$emailFrom;
   $txt ="You have received an e-mail from " .$name.".\n\n".$message;
    if ( mail( $mailTo, $headers, $txt ) ) {
        //メール送信完了の処理
    } else {
        //メール送信失敗の処理
    }
}else {
    //ここは一つでも空の値がある場合の処理
}
```

となります。
さらにはメールフォーマットのチェックや、エラーメッセージのXSS対策なども必要になってくるとは思います。引き続きマニュアルを確認しながらやってみてください。

Comment: すごくわかりやすい解説ありがとうございます。マニュアル読みながら理解をさらに深めていこうと思います。無事命令通りになりました。